# How to access elements in 'square bracket' multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hi So I have a 'database' .. which is my word for an array stored in a php file that I included in my page. It looks something like this:

```
$articles = [
['Title1', 'Category1', 'PATH1'],
['Title2', 'Category2', 'PATH2'],
['Title3', 'Category3', 'PATH3']
];
```

If I want to use print_r on a row it is easy:

```
print_r($articles[1]);
```

If I want to take a single cell from row 1 I could do this:

```
$article = $articles[1];
print $article[2]; // prints PATH
```

But I don't understand why:

```
print $articles[1][2]; // doesn't work
```

doesn't work. Is the syntax wrong or have I misunderstood what's going on with the Array. Why does it print out the word 'array' if I just want to try and print() $articles ? I suppose I am asking about what is happening with print() versus print_r().

On a side note, when looking for answers about this, I often didn't find people are using this square bracket 'Python-like' syntax.. Lots of pages are advocating the use of the array() function or the '=>' syntax, both of which seem quite tedious compared to my version.

Thanks

Comment: `print $articles[1][2];` works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/PSC6V

Comment: check the `$articles`, maybe you rewrite it...

Comment: In terms of your side-note, use whatever notation you prefer. Personally I prefer `array()`, but that's just me.

Comment: Okay. Right it is working now, maybe there was a typo somewhere. Thanks for your replies. Admins, feel free to remove if required.

Comment: You can delete your own question. Regarding the `=>` syntax— you have to use that to name the key unless you write a bunch of separate statements.  I too like the terseness of the square brackets, especially when passing an array to a method.  My personal bugaboo is seeing all these `<?php echo $somevar; ?>` when `<?= $somevar ?>` would do :p

Comment: I'm happy to leave it on here. Right, good point about the Key. Passing Array to Method. Okay. Oh that's interesting. Didn't know about the <?= syntax. Fantastic. Thanks for sharing. Chris

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print the data from the database with var_dump?

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($articles);
```

When you print the result, it should be in the following format:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Title1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Category1"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "PATH1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Title2"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Category2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "PATH2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Title3"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Category3"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "PATH3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well noted. It turned out there was a typo somewhere in my system so actually $articles[1][2] works as expected. Thanks. Chris